# How do I make the contents of a list go into an unordered map using a function as an argument?

Tags: c++, list, visual-c++, unordered-map

I'm looking for basically what the title is; the context required for the code is as shown. After that, I also want to display the map on screen, and then delete all of the contents of the list and map before clearing them.
Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
    list<Student *> tAllStudents;
    unordered_map<int, Student*> tSuperMap;
    while (true)
    {
        int a;
        string b;
        double c;
        cout << "What is the ID of the student? Enter -1 to cancel.";
        cin >> a;
        if (a == -1) { break; }
        else
        {
            cout << "What is the last name of the student?";
            cin >> b;
            cout << "What is the student's GPA?";
            cin >> c;

            Student* newS = new Student(a, b, c);
            tAllStudents.push_back(newS);
        }
    }
    for (auto iter = tAllStudents.begin(); iter != tAllStudents.end(); iter++)
    {
        /*here should be where it's done, where the ID (an internal variable in student) is the key, and the value is the Student object itself, which when the list prints will display its 'LastName' and 'GPA' as well*/
    }
}
```

Any other assistance is appreciated as well!

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't here to do your homework.   Give it a shot and if you have problems, post the actual code you've written to do it and say what's not going right.

Comment: @xaxxon unfortunately it mostly is. its rare to find a non acedemic question in C++, let alone a well written one.

Comment: @johnathan just because a question is common doesn't mean you should indulge it.

Answer (score 2):

```
   #include<list>
   #include<map>
   #include<unordered_map>
   #include<memory>
   #include<string>
   #include<iostream>

   using namespace std;

   struct Student{
    Student(int a, string b, double c) : ID(a) ,
    Name(b),
    Gpa(c){}
    int ID;
    string Name;
    double Gpa;
   };

   int main()
   {
    list<std::unique_ptr<Student>> tAllStudents;
    std::unordered_map<int, unique_ptr<Student>> tSuperMap;
    while (true)
    {
        int a;
        string b;
        double c;
        cout << "What is the ID of the student? Enter -1 to cancel.";
        cin >> a;
        if (a == -1) { break; }
        else
        {
            cout << "What is the last name of the student?";
            cin >> b;
            cout << "What is the student's GPA?";
            cin >> c;

            //Student* newS = new Student(a, b, c);
            tAllStudents.push_back(make_unique<Student>(a,b,c));
        }
    }
    for (auto iter = tAllStudents.begin(); iter != tAllStudents.end(); iter++)
    {
        /*here should be where it's done, where the ID (an internal variable in student) is the key, and the value is the Student object itself, which when the list prints will display its 'LastName' and 'GPA' as well*/
        tSuperMap[(*iter)->ID] = std::move(*iter);    

    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you must store a pointer in a container use either unique_ptr or shared_ptr. Map insertions happens when you present a new key to it. unordered_map is no different as it's a hash container. You've already got container iteration down. I'm certian you can figure out how to print your map object.

Comment: @xaxxon itr is an iterator that requires dereferencing to get at its Student* contents. Understand it now?

Comment: I'd edit the answer to emphasize that there's not much of a point to storing a pointer to `Student` in a `list` in modern C++. If they have `unordered_map`, they have move semantics and `emplace_back`.

Comment: @user4581301 I in no way disagree with you, but can I get this gentleman using smart pointers and not causing memory leaks too?